# how to accept tabnine suggestion?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, plugin-coc, plugin-tabnine

I'm using tabnine and COC.

I have a ~/.vimrc with the following lines:

```
inoremap <expr> <C-j> pumvisible() ? "\<C-N>" : "j"                                                                                                       
inoremap <expr> <C-k> pumvisible() ? "\<C-P>" : "k"
```

and they let me use CTRL+j/k to navigate the suggestions.

I saw that clicking the right arrow "chooses" the suggestion by tabnine, but couldn't bind it to anything (enter, space, etc.)

How to I do thatim

Answer (score 2):

You can check `:h :coc-completion` for a mapping suggestion.

It goes like so:

```
inoremap <expr> <cr> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<CR>"
```

In `popupmenu`, `<c-y>` (`ctrl-y`), accepts the suggestion (see `:h :popupmenu-keys`).

I like `ctrl-space` better, and I want it to show the menu if it's not displayed yet, so I do:

```
inoremap <expr> <c-space> pumvisible() ? coc#_select_confirm() : coc#refresh()
```